# Как сделать связь кнопок Button с одним из полей Entry, множество которых сгенерировано через цикл for?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, lambda

Есть маленькое приложение, которое загружает из файла маленькую таблицу. Из этой таблицы формируются две колонки из Entry-элементов. При вводе в строку Entry из левой колонки, обработанные данные должны выводиться в соответствующей строке правой колонки. Символы вводятся мышкой, не с клавиатуры - поэтому клик по кнопке с символом должен ввести его в ту строку левой колонки, на которой есть фокус:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод обработанных данных в строке соответствующей колонки справа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос заключается в том, как мне установить через фокус связь отдельной пары Entry между собой. Т.е. при клике на один из элементов Entry левой колонки и после ввода символов, вводимый текст был в одной строке левой колонки, а результат появился бы в соответствующей строке правой колонки.

---

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd
import re
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.title("GUI на Python")
root.configure(background='gray30')
root.geometry("380x580+10+20")

# root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
# root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "gray30")

def exitWindow():
    global root
    root.quit()

class CreateEntry:
    def __init__(self, index, row):
        self.operator = ''
        self.text_input = StringVar()
        self.text_output = StringVar()
        self.txtDisplayInput = ''

        row['id'] = tk.Frame(height=2, bd=0, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
        inputFrame = tk.Frame(row['id'], background="#2C2F33")
        row['id'].pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=1)
        txtDisplayInput = Entry(row['id'],
                                font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),
                                textvariable=self.text_input,
                                takefocus=True,
                                bd=10,
                                insertwidth=6,
                                width=16,
                                bg="ivory2",
                                justify='left')
        txtDisplayInput.grid(columnspan=7, column=0, row=index, sticky="NSEW")
        txtDisplayInput.focus()
        labelinp = Label(txtDisplayInput, text=row['formulae'], font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), justify=RIGHT).place(x=120)
        txtDisplayOutput = Entry(row['id'],
                                 font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),
                                 textvariable=self.text_output,
                                 bd=10,
                                 insertwidth=6,
                                 width=12,
                                 bg="ivory2",
                                 justify='left')
        txtDisplayOutput.grid(column=7, row=index, sticky="NSEW")
        labeloutp = Label(txtDisplayOutput, text=row['sign'], font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), justify=RIGHT).place(x=100)

    def btn_equel_disp(self):
        pass

    def btn_click_num(self, num):
        self.num = num
        operator = self.operator + str(self.num)
        self.text_input.set(operator)

    def btn_clear_disp(self):
        self.operator = ''
        self.text_input.set('')
        self.text_output.set('')

def openFile():
    global dataFrame
    path = fd.askopenfile()
    data = pd.read_csv(path, sep=",")
    data.columns = ['id', 'formulae', 'sign']
    dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
    return handler()

def handler():
    global arr
    arr = []
    for index, row in dataFrame.iterrows():
        index = CreateEntry(index, row)
        arr.append(index)

bottomFrame = tk.Frame(height=112, bd=0, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
bottomFrame.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, expand=True)
# ================================++============================
btn1 = Button(bottomFrame, padx=6, bd=5, fg='black', font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
              text='1', bg='LightGoldenrod1', command=lambda: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(1)).grid(row=2, sticky=NSEW, column=0)
btn2 = Button(bottomFrame, padx=6, bd=5, fg='black', font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
              text='2', bg='LightGoldenrod1', command=lambda: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(2)).grid(row=2, sticky=NSEW, column=1)
btn3 = Button(bottomFrame, padx=6, bd=5, fg='black', font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
              text='3', bg='LightGoldenrod1', command=lambda: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(3)).grid(row=2, sticky=NSEW, column=2)
btn4 = Button(bottomFrame, padx=10, bd=5, fg='black', font=('arial', 19, 'bold'),
              text='4', bg='LightGoldenrod1', command=lambda: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(4)).grid(row=2, sticky=NSEW, column=3)
btn5 = Button(bottomFrame, padx=10, bd=5, fg='black', font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
              text='5', bg='LightGoldenrod1', command=lambda: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(5)).grid(row=2, sticky=NSEW, column=4)
btn6 = Button(bottomFrame, padx=10, bd=5, fg='black', font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
              text='6', bg='LightGoldenrod1', command=lambda: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(6)).grid(row=2, sticky=NSEW, column=5)
# ================================++============================
btn7 = Button(bottomFrame, padx=6, bd=5, fg='black', font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
              text='7', bg='LightGoldenrod1', command=lambda: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(7)).grid(row=3, sticky=NSEW, column=0)
btn8 = Button(bottomFrame, padx=6, bd=5, fg='black', font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
              text='8', bg='LightGoldenrod1', command=lambda: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(8)).grid(row=3, sticky=NSEW, column=1)
btn9 = Button(bottomFrame, padx=6, bd=5, fg='black', font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
              text='9', bg='LightGoldenrod1', command=lambda: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(9)).grid(row=3, sticky=NSEW, column=2)
btn0 = Button(bottomFrame, padx=10, bd=5, fg='black', font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
              text='0', bg='LightGoldenrod1', command=lambda: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(0)).grid(row=3, sticky=NSEW, column=3)
clear = Button(bottomFrame, padx=10, bd=5, fg='black', font=('arial', 19, 'bold'),
              text='c', bg='LightGoldenrod1', command=lambda: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_clear_disp()).grid(row=3, sticky=NSEW, column=4)
equel = Button(bottomFrame, padx=10, bd=5, fg='black', font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
              text='=', bg='LightGoldenrod1', command=lambda: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_equel_disp).grid(row=3, sticky=NSEW, column=5)
# ================================++============================

bottomFrame.bind("<Return>", lambda event, btn=equel: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_equel_disp)
bottomFrame.bind("<Delete>", lambda event, btn=clear: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_clear_disp())
bottomFrame.bind("9", lambda event, num='9', btn=btn9: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(num))
bottomFrame.bind("8", lambda event, num='8', btn=btn8: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(num))
bottomFrame.bind("7", lambda event, num='7', btn=btn7: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(num))
bottomFrame.bind("6", lambda event, num='6', btn=btn6: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(num))
bottomFrame.bind("5", lambda event, num='5', btn=btn5: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(num))
bottomFrame.bind("4", lambda event, num='4', btn=btn4: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(num))
bottomFrame.bind("3", lambda event, num='3', btn=btn3: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(num))
bottomFrame.bind("2", lambda event, num='2', btn=btn2: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(num))
bottomFrame.bind("1", lambda event, num='1', btn=btn1: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(num))
bottomFrame.bind("0", lambda event, num='0', btn=btn0: ?????ЧТО ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ????.btn_click_num(num))


def flash(self, btn):
    """
    Flashes a corresponding button when key is pressed.
    :param btn: button
    :return: None
    """
    pass


main_menu = Menu()
file_menu = Menu()
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Открыть", command=openFile)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Выйти", command=exitWindow)
root.config(menu=main_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=file_menu)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Корень проблемы, я так понимаю, в command=lambda кнопок, но из-за неопытности не могу понять, что делать дальше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, на данный момент не имею возможности подробно изучить твой код, но могу посоветовать почитать вот это: [События в Tkinter](https://younglinux.info/tkinter/event.php)

Еще могу посоветовать следующий алгоритм: привязать событие щелчка левой кнопки мыши на все объекты Entry, которое помещает свое название в определенную переменную. Обработчик события щелчка кнопки считывает название Entry и помещает свое значение в указанный виджет.

Comment: спасибо! попробую